# keeping the one view on the front and doing another activity in Android

Tags: android, view, timer, background

I want to play the audio file in my application but the condition is that I want to play the selected sound file in background that means when the Timer CountDown(I have created one separate View for the Timer CountDown) gets over the audio file should play with the Same Timer CountDown View as it is.

The Timer CountDown Layout View should be maintained and the audio file should be played.

Can anyone please help me here because I am able to play the selected file finely, but All I want to do is just to play it with the Timer CountDown View maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you playing the audio file? With [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) you should be able to achieve what you want.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097909/playing-bg-music-across-activities-in-android) question could also be helpful.