# Android knowing if music is playing in specific instance of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'd like to know if my Specific MediaPlayer instance is playing sound/music.
MediaPlayer has the *isPlaying* method but it returns true even if the player is buffering and not playing.

Any idea how to know if MediaPlayer **really** plays sound?

Thanks.

Comment: can you use a MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener to tell you anything?

Comment: maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499037/android-mediaplayer-chopping-in-background

Comment: I know AudioManager can be used, but it's general and not for a specific MediaPlayer.

Comment: @didnh, OnBufferingUpdateListener can return always buffering, even while playing and while not playing.

Comment: @didnh, Chopping isn't related to this. Sorry.

Comment: Well, I maintain an `isPaused` flag, and set it to true/false when I pause/start the MediaPlayer for my applications. But I am not sure if there is an actual method which answers your question.

Comment: Sometimes I don't have control over the state of the player, like pausing/playing using a headpiece button or when buffering.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the state of **AudioPlayer** by **isMusicActive()** method by respective method.
The code snippet is as below :

```
AudioManager ar = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(ar.isMusicActive()) {
    //used
}
```

Comment: Tried it and, as with MediaPlayer.isPlaying(), even if the music isn't playing (like buffering), the value is still true.

Comment: Also, it is a too generic method and does not query the specific MediaPlayer instance.

Comment: i have one problem when i stop the mediaplayer it is not stopping while opening app again