# Preferred way to add background music to Android game?

Tags: android, background-music

I want to add background music to my Android game, this needs to be pause able, resume able, etc.

I have found this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

However the line

```
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder).getService();
```

Seems to kick up really weird errors, I have no idea what this is trying to do..

If anyone can see how to get this way working or if there is another, better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive looking, I have found this other question: [Playing BG Music Across Activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097909/playing-bg-music-across-activities-in-android)

Which points to this code: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

Which seems to work fine. Not sure if this is the best way..

Comment: You should not only put link in your answer. If the links don't work anymore then your answer is useless.

Comment: Your link is not working anymore but here is almost the same solution https://github.com/44maagnum/princetron_android/blob/master/src/princeTron/UserInterface/MusicManager.java

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder)binder).getService();
```

Its working for me. Also Change getService() method in MusicService class as public method.

Answer (score 1):

***Try to use***

```
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder) binder).getService();
```

with making getService() public

```
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder)binder).getService();
```