# How to set a music to image file in eclipse(android)?

Tags: android

This is my app I need to set a music(background) for this application

**my MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread Timer =new Thread( ){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(1000);
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.SPLASH"));

                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer.start();

    }




}
```

**My Second activity**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    LinearLayout bt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, third.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PINNI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you still using Eclipse for Android?

Comment: Really? I find Eclipse to be slower than Android Studio...

Comment: Thanks for your response @cricket_007 but i'm not looking for that. what exact i'm looking is when you open your app music also play automatically. i hope you understand my problem.

Comment: I do understand the problem, and you need to "play an audio file" from `onCreate` in the Activity.

Comment: when you open games app how the music is playing.. that exactly i need

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? You need an mp3 file and you open it and play it with the MediaPlayer class. None of the code you provided here attempts to do that, so I don't know what you want other than to simply play an audio file.

Comment: Dude i think u didn't understand my issue. i dont want to retrieve music from my sd card. i want to give a default audio file to my app. my issue is i have 3 images. i created splash screen when i open my app automatically the audio file has to play background. do you know temple run or candy crash games when you the game the default music is running by the same way. i need to put a some music

Comment: "i want to give a default audio file to my app" ... In order to do that, you **need an mp3 file**

Comment: This topic is still a duplicate, such as [Preferred way to add background music to Android game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591447/preferred-way-to-add-background-music-to-android-game) and [Play background music in all activities of Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579765/play-background-music-in-all-activities-of-android-app)

Comment: Thank you so much. it works for me. The only thing is audio is not stooping.