# Updating Ui Components in Activity based on MediaPlayer object from Service While Playing music files in background

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an Android music player based on the tutorial from Android Hive here is the link.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Which is tutorial for creating an music player like this.

[image]

Now I have successfully created my customized music player using this tutorial but their is a problem in that i.e. it doesn't play music in background. So searched for it and found this post

[Playing BG Music Across Activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097909/playing-bg-music-across-activities-in-android)

and I have found that I have to run MediaPlayer class from `Android Service`. So I used Android Service , created methods for play and pause and now my background music is running successfully.

**Now here is the main problem**

How can I update this components from the service which are dependent on MediaPlayer object like **seekbar**, **Timer** e.t.c. I am not able to get that.

Because these are dependent on media player object and MediaPlayer object is now in Service.

Comment: You should be able to use a Runnable and a Handler to update it from the background.

Comment: @Cornholio But in runnable and handler also. I need to calculate the total duration of the file from the MediaPlayer instance. So how to access it.

Comment: Store it statically in your Application class, that should work

Answer (score 2):

I am just near to finish my Music app now.
I have study this code of the Android Default Music app. which help me a lot.

You can see that here: [Platform_pkg_App_for_Music](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/tree/master/src/com/android/music)

Comment: How cam I download this project

Comment: its git repository. You just have to install plugin for git repository and import project from there.

Comment: @Droid Explorer Please can you provide me link to that plugin for linux fedora 17.

Comment: Ya I know that but I found it for windows but not able to find it for fedora.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use Custom `BroadcastReceiver` , You can send song name , artist etc details in `PutExtra` and inside `Activity` you need to create `OnReceiver()` and you can get this details using `intent.getStringExtra("message");`

Write this in **ServiceA.java**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("message","hi");
 intent.setAction("com.android.activity.SEND_DATA");
 context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Write this in **ActivityA.java**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // Extract data included in the Intent
   String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
   Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};
```

Now register `Receiver`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
  new IntentFilter("com.android.activity.SEND_DATA"));
```

Comment: really a nice answer +1 for you. I will get back to you here only after Implementing it.

Comment: @Er.NikhilAgrawal i have faced same problem and it worked like charm and my problem was solved .

Comment: very true. otherwise I have mailed this query to the author of that post 3 days back but he haven't replied for that.