# Controlling Background Music android

Tags: android, background

I am using a Service to play background Music. The problem is that the music continues playing when i have finished the activity. when i press home button the music stop i want to make music continue playing while application is use and stop when home button press help me please. can some tell me how to do this

```
private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;

}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    player.start();

    return 1;


}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO



}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}
public void onPause() {



    }


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {




}
```

}

Comment: You just Stop MediaPlayer into Activity onPause(). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service and play the music.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Service runs in the background so  even when you switch activities it still runs and you can play your music there.

You can start a service and then stop it when you need. Also you can bind the service to the activity. Look at the docs in the above link for more info.

Example :

https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
            // song is res/raw/yourmusicfile.mp3
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Now just start the service and you can stop the service when you need. You can switch between activities and the service still runs playing the music.

Since the code i huge i uploaded to DropBox. Here's the sample i made

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjc4krpcwsg7qm6/ServicesDemo.zip

Comment: @user3153271 the example for service with background music is there is the link posted please check

Comment: @user3153271 simple example of playing music is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028672/379693

Comment: @user3153271 it does work that is a working example. Pls also mention your updated code and what is that is not working.

Comment: @user3153271 pls look at the edit in my post. Posted a link to the drobox and you can download and modify the same accordingly